# Correct or preferred preposition after noob

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What would be the preferred preposition after "noob", as in, "I'm a noob `[preposition]` programming"? Would that be "to", as in, "I'm a newcomer to x"? (I assume you would use the same preposition after "noob" and "newbie".)

Comment: I'd say: "I am a noob *in*  programming...."

Comment: You would usually say *"I'm a programming noob"*.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, good point, I had overlooked that.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-complete-noob-in-programming-be-a-programmer-and-how-can-he-learn-the-things-taught-in-computer-science

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ngram to the rescue...

Noob in/at/on  does not register in Ngram but if you calque it on newbie, it seems that

> **newbie in**

wins, followed closely by at and on ex-aequo.

[image]
It seems that Noob is mostly used as a standalone noun as in "I'm a noob". If you take in-at-on out of the equation this word get lot of hits.

[image]

but as standalone newbie is still the king.

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the Ngram Viewer. Apparently, "newbie to" is even more frequent than "newbie in": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=newbie+in%2Cnewbie+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnewbie%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnewbie%20to%3B%2Cc0.

Comment: right, I forgot to add "to" to the mix, you can answer your question yourself then or I can edit mine to take account of it. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. And yes, I can answer my own question now ;-)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe , Probertelli, Problem with these Ngrams is that they don't tell you what is coming after the preposition. If you actually look at the examples you'll find they are mostly things like "invited a newbie to the bar", "put a newbie in charge of the programme", "met a lovely new newbie at work" and so on and so forth. So this tells you nothing at all about "newbie [preposition] activity/job". :(

Comment: @Araucaria Good catch. I'll need to look into that when I have some more time.